# Importing fields in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible to import fields from other classes? 
For eg.

```
class X(models.Model)
    field1 = models.
    field2 = models.

#Import these fields in to Class Y

class Y(models.Model)
    field3 = models.ForiegnKey('FK') #don't worry about FK
    field4 = #import here from field 1
    field5 = #import here from field 2
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider using an [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) instead.

Comment: Will it be possible to query the abstract class?

Comment: No. Only concrete models can be queried.

Comment: You could use model inheritance, but you'll soon come to hate it.